# How can I select values that are not translated from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

My knowledge of MySQL is basic and this is the first time I have faced this problem.

I have 3 tables, status, languages, and translations.

**Languages Table**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| language_id   | language_name | language_code |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1             | English       | en            |
| 2             | Español       | es            |
| 3             | Italiano      | it            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Status Table**

```
+--------------+
| pt_status_id |
+--------------+
| 1            |
| 2            |
+--------------+
```

**Translations Table**

```
+-----------+---------+----------+---------+----+
| tr_status    | tr_name         | tr_lang      |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------+----+
| 1            | for rent        | en           |
| 2            | for sale        | en           |
| 1            | alquiler        | es           |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

I am trying to get the values ​​that are not translated. In this example:

- `for sale` is not translated to Spanish
- `for rent` is not translated to Italian
- `for sale` is not translated to Italian

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT languages.*, tr_name, tr_lang FROM languages 
LEFT JOIN tr_ptstatus ON tr_lang = language_code 
WHERE tr_status IN (
    SELECT tr_status 
    FROM tr_ptstatus 
    GROUP BY tr_status HAVING count(*) < (SELECT count(*) FROM languages)
)
```

I also created a link in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3ad12/1

Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Barmar was correct, a simple approach to this type of problem is to first compute a matrix of all the possible combinations

```
SELECT DISTINCT pt_status_id, language_code
FROM tr_ptstatus
CROSS JOIN language
```

Because the output is simply Ids, we have to make a decision what language to display the results in to make this easier for the user to process the information, in the following result set you will see that in the second column we use a nested lookup to obtain the english translation of the status codes based on the observation that English is fully defined.

> Always return the Id from the source table, in this case 'pt_status_id' so you can pickup on status codes that have not yet even been translated into English.

Now your final SQL is this:

```
SELECT t1.pt_status_id
  ,(SELECT tr_name FROM tr_ptstatus WHERE tr_lang = 'en' and tr_status = t1.pt_status_id) as 'English'
  , language_code
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT pt_status_id, language_code
    FROM pt_status
    CROSS JOIN languages
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN tr_ptstatus AS t2 ON t1.pt_status_id = t2.tr_status AND t1.language_code = t2.tr_lang
WHERE t2.tr_status IS NULL
```

Results in:

```
pt_status_id    English         language_code   
1               For Sale        it              
2               For Rent        it              
1               For Sale        es
```

---

As a general design discussion, for issues like this I would normally choose the 'or default' language and put the default definition in the `tr_ptstatus` (*Status Defintion*) table, that way for issues like this the default readable value is available without too many sub-queries.

The added benefit of having a default string value or default translation in the status table direct is that it will become very easy to develop the bulk of your application and add translations later, or in parallel to the development.

A convention I have used before when I wanted *ALL* values to be translated or managed by another team (don't let developers write content that the end user will see) is to wrap all default values in [square brackets], or make them ALL CAPS. The reality is that the need for a default value to show always comes up, in your case we have said that it is 'English' but nothing about your data schema explains this to the user, we have to observe all values to come to that conclusion

> Try to establish database schemas that explain or document the way that you intent the data to be written, Normalisation for the sake of Normalisation alone can be very cryptic if you're not careful.

---

#### Update:

> Q: How can I include the name of the language in this result set?

This is where you get to flex your SQL muscle :), a simple way is to join back onto the `languages` table via the `language_code` and you will gain access to any of the other fields in that table.

- we demonstrated using a sub query before, this time we'll add a join:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN languages ON t1.language_code = languages.language_code
  ```

  But we will also need to add a new field into the `SELECT` clause, or you could replace the previous reference to `language_code` as a select column.

```
SELECT t1.pt_status_id
  ,(SELECT tr_name FROM tr_ptstatus WHERE tr_lang = 'en' and tr_status = t1.pt_status_id) as 'English'
  , languages.language_name
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT pt_status_id, language_code
    FROM pt_status
    CROSS JOIN languages
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN tr_ptstatus AS t2 ON t1.pt_status_id = t2.tr_status AND t1.language_code = t2.tr_lang
LEFT JOIN languages ON t1.language_code = languages.language_code
WHERE t2.tr_status IS NULL
```

---

### Q: if also i want to get tr_lang, tr_status from tr_ptstatus table, how i can do that?

Firstly, it wouldn't make sense to return these fields from the `tr_ptstatus` table for the languages that have not yet been translated, as these fields would be null.

If however you want to see these additional fields from the *English* translation, then we need to change the query so that the *default* or *reference* language (in this case *English* is `JOIN`ed onto the query so we can easily access any additional fields.

> As a general rule, selecting fields from `JOIN`ed tables is more performant than using sub-queries. However us the of sub-queries can often make the code more readable or maintainable, the performance impact of a small number of subqueries is usually not noticeable, but if you need to retrieve more than one single column from a sub-query, you should consider using `JOIN` syntax instead.

In the following query, a `JOIN` replaces the *sub-query* however you will find that there is not a great deal of meaning to returning `tr_status` from each of the tables as this query uses that common field value to link all the tables, as you can see in the results, they are all the same, except for the value from the missing translation table, it is `NULL` because there is no corresponding row to select a value from.

```
SELECT t1.pt_status_id
  , ref.tr_name as 'Reference'
  , languages.language_name
  , t2.tr_lang, t2.tr_status
  , ref.tr_lang as 'Ref Lang', ref.tr_status as 'Ref Status'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT pt_status_id, language_code
    FROM pt_status
    CROSS JOIN languages
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN tr_ptstatus AS t2 ON t1.pt_status_id = t2.tr_status AND t1.language_code = t2.tr_lang
LEFT JOIN languages ON t1.language_code = languages.language_code
LEFT JOIN tr_ptstatus AS ref ON ref.tr_lang = 'en' and ref.tr_status = t1.pt_status_id
WHERE t2.tr_status IS NULL;
```

```
pt_status_id    Reference   language_name   tr_lang tr_status   Ref Lang    Ref Status
1               For Sale    Español         (null)  (null)      en          1
1               For Sale    Italiano        (null)  (null)      en          1
2               For Rent    Español         (null)  (null)      en          2
```

Comment: I already have a setting table in which the default language is defined, then i could get the default language and replace it with  'en', right?

Comment: Yeah that's correct, i was hoping by making that a sub-query it would be easy for you to put your own logic like that in there.

Comment: if for example i want to get the name of the language, how do i add it to the query?

Comment: I've updated the solution with some guidance on this

Comment: Hi @Chris Schaller if also i want to get tr_lang, tr_status from tr_ptstatus table, how i can do that?

Comment: I have updated a final edit for this, it doesn't make a lot of sense to show those columns, especially `tr_status` I hope the information around this is sufficient, this answer covers a lot of the basic mechanics around joins and selecting columns

Comment: I think now is a complete answer and solution for the problem, thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you all values which have not been translated into all other languages:

```
SELECT t.tr_status,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.tr_lang = 'en' THEN t.tr_name END) AS tr_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.tr_lang) AS languages
FROM tr_ptstatus t
GROUP BY t.tr_status
HAVING COUNT(*) < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM languages)
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
tr_status   tr_name     languages
1           For Sale    en
2           For Rent    en,es
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3d45/5)

Comment: I think he is not doing that, because he simply grouped the languages ​​that each value has

Comment: @bdroid if any of the words have all 3 languages, they will not be displayed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d31edd/1

Comment: Can you explain to me exactly what this line does? MIN(CASE WHEN t.tr_lang = 'en' THEN t.tr_name END)

Comment: The `CASE` expression returns the English translation or `NULL`, putting it in a `MIN` allows the expression to be used in this query without violating `GROUP BY` constraints.

Comment: The use of the `MIN` around the `CASE` expression is called conditional aggregation, it's a topic worth reading about. It allows you to select a specific value from a set of rows (in this case the `English` translation of each phrase)

Comment: on sqlfiddle is working fine but when i print_r the results 
it shows me too For Rent en,es see the screenshot: https://snipboard.io/xObHJV.jpg

Comment: @bdroid I changed the data in the SQLFiddle to demonstrate the query when a phrase had all languages (I added `(2, 'it', 'In Affito'),` to `tr_ptstatus`)

Comment: You're listing the languages that exist for each message, I think he wants the missing languages.

Comment: @Barmar yes - but I'm only listing the messages which don't have have *all* the translations, so it's reasonably simple to go from this output to what needs to be done. OP only asks for the values which are not translated, and this query is very close to OPs original one. So I feel it's a reasonable answer. Note I have upvoted the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

Write a subquery that generates a table of all combinations of status and languages. Then `LEFT JOIN` this with all the translations, to find the missing combinations.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT pt_status_id, language_code
    FROM tr_ptstatus
    CROSS JOIN languages
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN translations AS t2 ON t1.pt_status_id = t2.tr_status AND t1.language_code = t2.tr_lang
WHERE t2.tr_status IS NULL
```